# understanding coefficients in negative binomial regression (glm.nb)

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, negative-binomial-distribution

Hi CrossValidated Community,

I have a very simple question about the interpretation of coefficients produced by fitting a negative binomial to some toy data. I generate the toy data by sampling from a negative binomial using four different mean values defined by the vector `untreated_avg`. I then repeated this process but with means defined by a second vector, `treated_avg`. I am looking to use the negative binomial regression to determine the effect of treatment (reproducible code chunk at end of question).

When the effect of treatment is the same for each of the four groups (`treated_avg <- untreated_avg*c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5`) then the exponentiated regression coefficients are consistent with the toy data and the intercept represents the untreated mean for group "A". In addition all coefficients have p-values <2e-16.

```
group_names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
untreated_avg <- c(1, 2, 4, 8)
treated_avg <- untreated_avg*c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
theta <- 2
samples <- 10000

Results:
print(exp(glm_model_fit$coefficients))
(Intercept)     treated      groupB      groupC      groupD 
  1.0149415   0.5019671   1.9499295   3.9294437   7.8858195 

  group treated `mean(incidents)`
  <chr>   <dbl>             <dbl>
1 A           0             1.01 
2 A           1             0.51 
3 B           0             1.97 
4 B           1             0.999
5 C           0             4.02 
6 C           1             1.98 
7 D           0             7.97 
8 D           1             4.04
```

My confusion is when the effect of treatment varies by group. I could introduce interaction terms to account for this but where interactions are not expected how can I interpret the coefficients and what should I be mindful of. To illustrate this I change the response of groups "C" and "D" to the treatment from 0.5 to 5 (`treated_avg <- untreated_avg*c(0.5, 0.5, 5, 5`). The following is contrary to what I expected and I would be very grateful for any explanation/insight:

It appears:

(1) The intercept no longer represents the untreated mean for group "A" but has decreased from 1 to 0.5.

(2) The coefficient for treatment (2.34) is not the mean treatment effect across the groups (2.75).

(3) The coefficients for groups C and D (12.9 and 25.6) are not consistent their untreated averages (~4 and ~8).

(4) The treatment coefficient again reports a p-value < 2e16 despite the large variance in effect-size across the different groups either side of 1.

```
group_names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
untreated_avg <- c(1, 2, 4, 8)
treated_avg <- untreated_avg*c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
theta <- 2
samples <- 10000

Results:
> print(exp(glm_model_fit$coefficients))
(Intercept)     treated      groupB      groupC      groupD 
  0.4912656   2.3443343   2.1530202  12.9072694  25.6466305 

  group treated `mean(incidents)`
  <chr>   <dbl>             <dbl>
1 A           0             0.971
2 A           1             0.502
3 B           0             2.00 
4 B           1             0.988
5 C           0             3.93 
6 C           1            20.0  
7 D           0             7.96 
8 D           1            39.8
```

Any insight on this from the community would be truly appreciated.

Reproducible example:

```
group_names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
untreated_avg <- c(1, 2, 4, 8)
treated_avg <- untreated_avg*c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
theta <- 2
samples <- 10000

experiment_df <- NULL
for(ii in 1:length(group_names)){

  untreated_df <- data.frame(incidents = rnegbin(n = samples,
                                                 untreated_avg[ii],
                                                 theta)) %>% 
    mutate(group = group_names[ii], treated = 0)
  
  
  treated_df <- data.frame(incidents = rnegbin(n = samples,
                                               treated_avg[ii],
                                               theta)) %>% 
    mutate(group = group_names[ii], treated = 1)
  
  experiment_df <- rbind(experiment_df, untreated_df, treated_df)
  
}

glm_model_fit <- glm.nb(incidents ~ treated + group, data=experiment_df)

print(exp(glm_model_fit$coefficients))
print(experiment_df %>% group_by(group, treated) %>% summarise(mean(incidents)))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you omit interactions, you are fitting the wrong model, you so should not expect the estimated coefficients to line up with the data they are meant to represent. The treatment coefficient is estimated assuming it is constant across groups. What you get is a weighted average of the group-specific coefficients, though, to my knowledge, it is not known how that weighted average is computed for nonlinear models.

To reproduce the observed means, you would need to fully saturate the model by including the interactions between treatment and group. In a more complex scenario, you can either include interactions between treatment and all covariates or use another method of estimating marginal effects, like propensity score weighting, if you wanted to arrive at a single average treatment effect.